# Rails 4 App - Heroku / Cloudfront - Assets not serving from origin properly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-cloudfront

I have a rails 4 application in which we are using cloudfront as the CDN.

In the `production.rb` file, we have the following code:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "example3579.cloudfront.net"
```

We have done some pretty thorough asset separation. This may not be advisable from an asset pipeline standpoint, but it should make debugging this issue pretty easy.

The particular page I'm working on is the `users#edit` view, but the problem is universal.

The `users#edit` action uses it's own layout: `views/layouts/user_edit.html.erb`

The `views/layouts/user_edit.html.erb` file calls this javascript.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'user_edit'%>
```

**assets/javascripts/user_edit.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.validate.min
//= require ./webarch/form_validations
```

On the localhost, this works. I can access the js in the browser like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/user_edit.js
```

But on production with heroku, the site looks for this file:

```
<script src="http://example3579.cloudfront.net/javascripts/user_edit.js"></script>
```

The file doesn't work. I can't access in the browser and the javascript does not render on the page. I have precompiled the assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production` # Helpful for rails 4 assets on heroku

And in /config/environments/production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

This should work

Comment: I have rails 12 factor, but `config.assets.compile = false`. Changing now.

Comment: That should be the solution, everything except the validation is working. I think that they may because the jquery validate is in the vendor folder. One sec.

Comment: Couldn't get jquery validation to work but I'm pretty sure that's a separate issue. Thanks

Comment: Guys why does 'config.assets.compile'  have to be set to true? According to heroku the rails_12factor gem does the same.